# Quotient fields of the subring of the rationals which contains all fractions where the denominator is not divisible by $p$

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory

Fix a prime $p$. Let $R := \{\frac{r}{s} \in \mathbb{Q}: p \nmid s\}$. $R$ is clearly a subring.

> **Proposition 1:** R is a principal ideal domain.

I prove it as follows:

> **Proof:** Suppose $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal in $R$. If $\mathfrak{a} = (0)$, or $\mathfrak{a} = (1) = R$, it is clearly principal. If it is proper, let $a:= \min\{x \in \mathfrak{a}\cap \mathbb{Z}^{>0}\}$. We claim $(a) = \mathfrak{a}$. Now clearly $(a)\subseteq\mathfrak{a}$, and $a = p^k$ for some $k>0$, as otherwise $1 = a \frac{1}{a} \in \mathfrak{a}$. For $x \in \mathfrak{a}$, we have $x = p^l\frac{r}{s}$, where $l>0$, $p \nmid r$ and $p \nmid s$. We must have $l\geq k$, as $l<k$ implies $p^l \in \mathfrak{a}$ ($\frac{r}{s}$ is a unit) which contradicts the minimailty of $a$. Hence $x = ap^{k-l}\frac{r}{s}$ and $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq (a)$.

Now the proof gave us that every (proper) ideal in $R$ is of the form $(p^k)$ for some $k>0$, and hence the only maximal ideal is $(p)$. We get that the only possible quotient field is $F:= \frac{R}{(p)}$. By considering the canonical homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow F$, we deduce that $\mathrm{char} F = p$.

My question is now whether my proof of the proposition is correct, whether $(p)$ is the only maximal ideal ($R$ being therefore a local ring) and hence $F$ is the only quotient field, and most importantly if there exist a different expression for $F$ or some 'standard' example of a field which is isomorphic to $F$. Is there a generalization of this construction? Or given an arbitrary domain $D$ and it's field of fractions $Q$, is there a relationship between the similarly constructed quotient field $F$ and $Q$ or $D$?

Comment: It's perfectly correct, and no, there's no direct relationship between the residue field of a local integral domain and its field of fractions. Note that, in the present case, the latter has characteristic $0$, the former has characteristic $p$